# Build access in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, alm, multibranch-pipeline

We are using multi branch pipeline in jenkins for all our GIT repositories.

For suppose we have 100 developers(divided into 2 groups) in team we would like to restrict build access to everyone based on branch names.

1. Developers who fall under group 1 can build any branch.
2. Developers who fall under group 2 can build only branches which starts with or contains feature or users.

Kindly let me know if it is possible to do in jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't trivial to manage that kind of separation within the same job, but if you could define 2 jobs per project:

- one allowing to build all branches
- one only for certain branch

You can then through [Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/security/#authorization), limit one group to a role which can be associated to the second type of projects.
That uses "project role", a role  that can be applied to only certain projects (i.e jobs) that match a certain pattern (naming convention).

Comment: Example: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/03/jenkins-users-groups-roles/